# Why is the 1-wire pull-up resistor not integral?

Tags: pullup, 1-wire

I've read that the 1-wire pullup resistor is included so that either the master or the slave device can pull the line low in order to communicate. Makes perfect sense: if the device had a transistor output stage pulling it high, then no other device would be able to commandeer the bus.

Most hobbyists seem to use the same resistor value. I have a suspicion this is not appropriate and that cable run is a factor here.

So, why is this critical resistor, which is always the same value for a given device, not integral to the device?

Answer (score 1):

Silly question. I just realised. You probably only want one pull-up per bus, whereas you might have many devices on that bus. For each parallel pullup, the resistance reduces.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this critical resistor, which is always the same value for a given device, not integral to the device?

One reason is that so many devices could be attached to the line. Let's say we use a 4.7 kΩ resistor for pull-up. The current sunk by a device pulling the line low would be 1 mA.

Now consider what happens if you have 100 devices on the bus, each with its own 4.7 kΩ pull-up. Any device trying to pull the line low would have to sink 100 mA. This has too bad effects:

- The 1-wire devices would have to have a much beefier open-collector transistor.
- It would be a problem for low-power systems as, for example, the battery would need to provide a much higher current.